# Cannot post a new user into mongodb with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a problem with POSTing new User into my mlab mongodb. I'm new to Node.
My console says:

> POST /signup - - ms - -

This is in my app.js

```
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var fs = require('fs');
var User = require('./models/User.js');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);
app.get('/form', function(req, res) {
  fs.readFile('./form.html', function(error, content) {
    if (error) {
      res.writeHead(500);
      res.end();
    } else {
      res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
      res.end(content, 'utf-8');
    }
  });
});
app.post('/signup', function(req, res) {
  var username = req.body.username;
  var password = req.body.password;
  User.addUser(username, password, function(err, user) {console.log(username, password);
    if (err) throw err;
    res.redirect('/form');
  });
});

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});


module.exports = app;
```

This in form.html

```
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
<form action="/signup" method="post">
  <div>
    <label>Uživatelské jméno:</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" /><br />
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Heslo:</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="submit" value="Registrovat" />
  </div>
</form>
```

db connection .../lib/db.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

module.exports.mongoose = mongoose;
module.exports.Schema = Schema;

// newclouddb
var username = "user";
var password = "password";
var address = '@dsxxxxxx.mlab.com:99999/gasdass';
connect();

// connectmongo
function connect() {
  var url = 'mongodb://' + username + ':' + password + address;
  mongoose.connect(url);
}

function disconnect() {mongoose.disconnect()}
```

This is my model of users models/User.js

```
var db = require('../lib/db');

var UserSchema = new db.Schema({
  username : {type: String, unique: true},
  password : String
});

var MyUser = db.mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

// Exporty
module.exports.addUser = addUser;

// add users to db
function addUser(username, password, callback) {
  var instance = new MyUser();
  instance.username = username;
  instance.password = password;
  instance.save(function (err) {
    if (err) {
      callback(err);
    } else {
      callback(null, instance);
    }
  });
}
```

I have no idea why it's not sending data to my db. Can someone take a look and tell me where I'm making a mistake? It would be really helpful.

Comment: You can start by looking for connection errors with `mongoose.set('debug', true)`, `mongoose.connection.on('connected', function () { console.log('connected'); })`, `mongoose.connection.on('error', function (err) { console.log(err); })` and `mongoose.connection.on('disconnected', function () { console.log('disconnected'); })` in db.js.

Comment: No connection errors has shown.

Comment: It only shows waiting for localhost...

Comment: Does the connected event trigger? Does it say *connected* at least?